# group by soql query

Tags: soql, group-by

I have records with same values in custom field, `Unique_Name__c`. On a `Visualforce Page`, I have to display records grouped by `Unique_Name__c`.

`Unique_Name__c` is custom field on `OpportunityLineItem` populated using a `Workflow Rule` from `Product2` object (product name).

So I have a query

```
SELECT Id, Unique_Name__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY Unique_Name__c
```

When I run this, I get an error saying:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: Id

When I change query to

```
SELECT Id, Unique_Name__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY Id
```

I get the following error:

> MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated: Unique_name__c

Can anyone please help me figuring this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an inherent irony in grouping by a field that claims in its API Name to be unique. Each grouping should theoretically contain just one record. It would perhaps make more sense if the field were simply renamed `Product_Name__c`. But I digress. If you are sure you want to do groupings, you can get the record count for each `Unique_Name__c` as follows:

```
SELECT count(Id) records, Unique_Name__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY Unique_Name__c
```

Any fields you want to query for individually must be grouped. You can group multiple fields, which would look like:

```
SELECT Id, Unique_Name__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY Id, Unique_Name__c
```

Or you can group just one:

```
SELECT Unique_Name__c
FROM OpportunityLineItem
GROUP BY Unique_Name__c
```

Comment: I had to read thrice your first few lines to understand what you are talking about but now I totally understand. Great analysis and observation!